# observation 3 in Stein's book chapter 1 $m_*(E)=\inf m_*(O)$

Tags: real-analysis

[image]The proof of $m_*(E)=\inf  m_*(O)$ where the infimum is taken over the open sets containing E.
There is one step I can not figure out.
$m_*(O) \le \sum_{j=1}^\infty m_*(Q_j^0)=\sum_{j=1}^\infty|Q_j^0|$ How this equality in the right part appear?
I think the exterior measure of $Q_j^0$ should greater or equal to the $|Q_j^0|$.Thank you.

Comment: You don't recite the context, but I suspect the $Q_j^0$ are pairwise disjoint?...

Comment: You don't explain the context, but I suspect $m_*$ is Lebesgue outer measure.

Comment: yes, $m_* $ is outer measure